# vue array reactivity for a dynamic array push

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want a two dimensional array which will have dynamic key and array of objects pushed to it, as you see I tried this.$set and Vue.set but got no success so far,

```
data() {
rep_recs: [] , // I want this array reactive..so I can display a table
recs:[] // actual data
},
created() {

    while(cond) {
                   //..some code
                   var y_m_key = `${Y}-${M}`

                   //  Vue.set(this.rep_recs, y_m_key,  [])
                   // this.$set(rep_recs, y_m_key,  [])
                   this.rep_recs[y_m_key] = []


                    for (var i=0; i<this.recs.length; i++) {
                        var rec = this.recs[i]
                        this.rep_recs[y_m_key].push(rec) //this works but not reactive
                    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this should work for you

```
var rec = this.recs[i]
this.$set(this.rep_recs, y_m_key, [
    ...this.rep_recs[y_m_key],
    rec
]);
```

This creates a new array everytime, which should solve the reactivity issue

Comment: ah!!..I hoped this would definitely work..it throws an error..

" Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: @CodeTree if you have a working example somewhere, i might be able to help with debugging